# Rails using wrong id in Object.find(params[:id]) when rendering partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models `Package` and `Item`and their relationship is defined in a REDIS set, so there is no rails relationship.  I'm having trouble setting an instance of `Item` in the `PackagesController`.

In `packages/show`

```
    <ul>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <li><a href="#" data-reveal-id="itemModal"><%= link_to item.item_name %></a></li>
    </ul>
    <% end %>

    <div id="itemModal" class="reveal-modal full" style="overflow: auto;" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
      <%= render 'items/item' %>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

In the `_item` partial

```
    <div>
      <h2><%= @item.item_name %></h2>
    </div>
```

In the `PackagesController`

```
    class PackagesController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @package = Package.find(params[:id])
        @items = @package.items  (items is the REDIS set showing items that belong to the package)
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

The problem is with `@item = Item.find(params[:id])`.  It is using the `package.id` to find the item.  For example, if the page is on `Package.id == 6`, then it will show `Item.id == 6` in the rendered partial, instead of the correct item that was clicked on.

How can I correctly set the value of `@item` while it's on the controller of a different model?

Comment: Which Item `id` do you want it to use? `params[:id]` is a Package `id` presumably because your route is something like `/packages/:id`; where is it that you want the Item `id` to come from?

Comment: I want the id to come from the specific items generated in the list of items.  Once the item in the list is clicked, I want the correct modal to show. The list of items come from a REDIS set so i can't use something like `@package.item'.